# Search files and delete them via SSH

Tags: file, search, ssh, command, delete-file

I would like to know which SSH command should I run to search for any file named error.log inside the whole server and delete them.

Any file named error.log must be deleted.

Comment: @BrianTompsett Don't bump this garbage. Leave it alone for users with delete-vote privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-how-to-find-and-remove-files/

```
find . -name "error.log" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

And also XARGS example from http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_delete_all_occurances_of_a_file_in_linux.html

```
find . -name "error.log" | xargs rm
```